# What's the simplest way to call an exported function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules, commonjs

I have a module `dotenv` which has a function `config` that I need to call once, first thing when the code runs.
With `CommonJS`, I could do:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

But with `ECMAScript`, I have to do the following:

```
import { config } from 'dotenv'
config()
```

Right now I also have this `config` function which I will never use again.
Is there a better way to call the function?

Comment: `Is there a better way to call the function?` Not that i can see. Is there a problem with the code you've written?

Comment: I'm not aware of a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a async import and execute the imported `config` directly. Something like:

```
// say [yourConfigLibrary] exports
// export default { config: _ => ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, configDone: true,}) };
// then you can import and run it in one line:
const config = (await import(`[yourConfigLibrary]`)).default.config();
```

See [this stackblitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-mmaa62?file=script.js), same for [nodejs](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-yr6u6s?file=index.js)

Comment: `await import('dotenv').default.config()` does not work?

Comment: @n1md7 Nope: the import should be resolved before it's usable.

Comment: I see. `(await import('dotenv')).default.config();` should do the trick then

Comment: Yup. That works too. Applied in the [nodejs snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-yr6u6s?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

I should've done a bit of research before asking the question, it seems like there is no better way.